# Change width of select options list

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to define width of select lists? If so, how to do it? 
The select tag doesn't have the attribute width.

```
<select data-bind="options: names, value: selectedName, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: Name, optionsCaption: Select Person"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr` binding, and set width in style:

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectWidth = ko.observable();
    self.selectWidthStyle = ko.computed(function() {
        return "width:" + self.selectWidth() + "px";
    });
}
```

Html:

```
<select data-bind="attr: {style: selectWidthStyle}"></select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexmac/9mHWh/)

Comment: If i want to hardcode the size then it will be something like: "attr: { style: { width: '500px'} }" ?

Comment: No, if you want the static width, then just add style to html: `<select style="width: 500px"></select>`

Comment: One more thing, How to do it in a css file, so all select lists can use same style ? Thank you.

Comment: Use this css: `select {width: 500px;}`

Answer (score 2):

Use css

```
<style>
    select { width: 30%; /*or something like it*/ }
</style>
```